# How to use TDengine docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, tdengine

How to use TDengine docker image in production?

How to use TDengine docker image in a docker-compose file?

How to use TDengine docker image in docker swarm?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is nothing special in using TDengine docker image and using docker compose file. The only two major points that users need to pay attention is port mapping (for exposing host port) and volume mount (for storing data on host to make it persistent). Again, there is nothing special to use TDengine with Docker swarm, but users possibly need to pay attention on the load balance and failover policy in swarm, it's recommended to make sure dnodes in one vgroup reside on different physical hosts.